# sudo apt-get install steam error

Tags: apt, steam

I've an error with installing steam;

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     gcc-5-multilib : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not going to be installed
     libc6-dev-x32 : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (= 2.23-0ubuntu5) but it is not going to be installed
     steam:i386 : Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.3) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libudev1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libxinerama1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libtxc-dxtn0:i386
          Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed
```

E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
 here

If I'm typing; `sudo apt-get -f install` there comes this:

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 Correcting dependencies... Done
 The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
      libstdc++-5-dev x11-apps xinit xorg-docs-core
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
libc6-dev-i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libc6-dev-i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 310 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1262 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6936 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 203569 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-dev-i386_2.23-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dev-i386 (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.23-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/include/fpu_control.h', which is also in package libc6-dev-amd64:i386 2.23-0ubuntu5
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.23-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```