# Why does "sudo apt-get install gpsd" return with errors?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, apt, steam, gps

I am trying to install `gpsd` on a Ubuntu laptop, using `sudo apt-get install gpsd`. It seemed to be fine when I installed this on 2 other Ubuntu laptops. There it works properly.

Here I did the same on 3rd laptop which has Ubuntu installed. Here I received this message:

```
root@Lab-X230:/home/igor# sudo apt-get install gpsd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-64-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-67-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-67-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-67-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-64-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic (= 4.4.0-64.85) but it is not going to be installed
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-66-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic (= 4.4.0-66.87) but it is not going to be installed
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-67-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-67-generic (= 4.4.0-67.88) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I also tried these commands:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install gpsd
```

Still it returned these error messages.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic linux-image-4.4.0-67-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-4.4.0 | linux-source-4.4.0 linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic linux-image-4.4.0-67-generic
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 224 not upgraded.
16 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/137 MB of archives.
After this operation, 199 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 588763 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-67-generic_4.4.0-67.88_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-67-generic (4.4.0-67.88) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-67-generic_4.4.0-67.88_amd64.deb (--unpack):
cannot copy extracted data for './boot/System.map-4.4.0-67-generic' to '/boot/System.map-4.4.0-67-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-67-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-67-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-67-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-67-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic_4.4.0-64.85_amd64.deb ...
Done.

Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic (4.4.0-64.85) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic_4.4.0-64.85_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-64-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-64-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error 
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-64-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-64-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-64-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-64-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic_4.4.0-66.87_amd64.deb ...
Done.

Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic (4.4.0-66.87) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic_4.4.0-66.87_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-66-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-66-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-66-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-66-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-66-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-66-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-67-generic_4.4.0-67.88_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic_4.4.0-64.85_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic_4.4.0-66.87_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

From this link: [sudo apt-get install steam error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882717/sudo-apt-get-install-steam-error) (because he had the same problem with me). But no one helped.

Does anyone see this problem and have any luck on this?

Comment: What kernel version are you running?  You might need to follow on this page for the 14.04 LTS Enablement Stack install:  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: @Terrance: **Linux version 4.4.0-57-generic (buildd@lgw01-54) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ) #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 9 23:50:32 UTC 2016
**

Comment: Have you tried to do a `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to see if there are any kernel updates to be installed?

Comment: @Terrance:  I have tried **sudo apt-get update** but not **sudo apt-get dist-upgrade**

Comment: @Terrance: when I use those commands for update, I also received messages similar this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/886140/this-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-error-ubuntu-16-04-64bit/890986 but there are no lucks when follow those instructions.

Comment: I would recommend editing your question then and putting in exactly the error messages you are getting when you try to do the `sudo apt-get -f install` or `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` as there might be slight variations in the message that you are getting vs the messages from the linked question you have.  Someone out there will probably know or has stumbled across it.  Exact messages are extremely helpful!

Comment: @Terrance: just uploaded error messages.

Comment: I see in your error message that you are out of space.  Check here:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/142926/cant-upgrade-due-to-low-disk-space-on-boot  That can be a HUGE problem.  You might want to also follow an old answer of mine to maybe autoremove old kernels from your system that are no longer needed.  http://askubuntu.com/a/620281/231142

Comment: @Terrance: following your answer from the link, I am trying to use this command: **sudo apt-get autoremove -f** and i did not have the same message as you had, but the message look like: **No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)**  and **E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)**

Comment: Try the second link http://askubuntu.com/a/620281/231142

Comment: @Terrance: I am talking about the second link you sent to me. There is no luck for me :(

Comment: Try the first link then.  You need to free up space on your `/boot` partition or you will not be able to move on from here.

Comment: @Terrance Easy on this one. You don't want to [pull a terdon](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/16191/75166) on him.

Comment: @MadMike I don't get how that applies?  I have not mentioned anything about deleting the /boot or anything like that.

Comment: @Terrance I shouldn't have skipped the ":-)" in my comment: I was trying to be funny :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can't install anything because your disc is full.

Excerpt from your question:

```
...
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-67-generic (4.4.0-67.88) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-67-generic_4.4.0-67.88_amd64.deb (--unpack):
cannot copy extracted data for './boot/System.map-4.4.0-67-generic' to '/boot/System.map-4.4.0-67-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
...
```

At the end last line from the excerpt it's written `(No space left on device)` So you need to free up some disk space before you can continue to install anything.

Use `df -h` to find out which drive has has no more space left.

If your boot-partition is full, you can delete old kernel images with the following command:

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -V | sed -n '/'`uname -r`'/q;p' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

which is copied from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu/254585#254585).

Comment: how to know my disc is full?

Comment: The part that says "No space left on device" should give you a clue.

Comment: @MadMike: when I use that command, everything just fine, but only this guy show me : **/dev/sda2                           473M  473M     0 100% /boot** . is it mean **out of space?**